# random prime number generator over one million is only giving prime numbers half the time

Tags: c++

I wish to find a random prime number over one million but my program only outputs one maybe half the time.
When it doesn't it will just output nothing.

```
unsigned long long int primeFinder(unsigned long long int base) {

    int flag = 0;
    unsigned long long int m = base / 2;
    for (int i = 2; i <= m; i++) {
        if (base%i == 0) {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag == 1) {
        base = base + 2;
        primeFinder(base);
    }
    else {
        return base;
    }
}

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    unsigned long long int base;
    base = 1000000;
    int number = rand() % 1000000;
    base += number;
    cout<<primeFinder(base);
}
```

I am assuming this is because of my if statement, but I am not too sure about how to ensure it will return a prime number. I am using visual studio express 2017.

Comment: I'd suggest breaking this up a bit more. Write a function that tests if a number is prime. Make sure it works. Then, using that function, write a function that tries to find a prime above a certain value. That being said, note that if `flag == 1`, you _call_ `primeFinder(base)` but you don't _return_ anything, you just flow off the end of the function. I'm surprised you didn't get [warning C4715](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4715?view=msvc-160) about this--or if you did, you ignored it.

Comment: mixing int with long long?

Comment: I would also suggest that recursion is not necessarily a great approach for this algorithm because you can have very long stretches of composite numbers, which will lead to very deep stacks. It's possible to fix this and compile it in such a way that MSVC recognizes that this is tail recursion and avoids stack overflow, but I'd still suggest rewriting it iteratively instead of recursively for clarity.

Comment: Note further that if `number` happens to be even (which should happen half the time), then `primeFinder` will never return anything because `base`, `base+2`, `base+4`, ... etc are all composite.

Comment: There's not much point in calling `primeFInder()` recursively if you're going to just throw away the result. This is in essence an iterative problem. Don't use recursion for iteration. Use iteration for iteration, and recursion when you need it, which you don't here.

Comment: Even if you did the recursion right, if you put in a even number it will only try other even numbers, so it will not find a prime.

Comment: Given that you are using `rand` and VS, could you also check the value of [`RAND_MAX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/rand-max?view=msvc-160)?

Comment: Why do you run until the half of your number? If it's just for checking prime, you can just go to the square root of the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you do not ensure that your starting point is an odd number. Since you recursively call `primeFinder()` incrementing the "`base`" by two, this will result in endless recursion when the starting point is an even number, i.e. about half the time.

An easy way to fix this is to change the initial call as follows:

```
    cout<<primeFinder(base|1);
```

Next, you only need to check for divisors up to the square root. This can be done by calculating `m` as follows:

```
    unsigned long long int m = llround(sqrt(base));
```

Remember to `#include<cmath>`.

Furthermore, I would recommend restructuring `primeFinder()` to avoid the recursion and have a separate function to determine if a given number is a prime:

```
bool isPrime(unsigned long long int n)
{
    unsigned long long int m = llround(sqrt(n));
    for (int i = 2; i <= m; i++) {
        if (n%i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return (n>1);
}

unsigned long long int primeFinder(unsigned long long int base)
{
    while(!isPrime(base))
    {
        base += 2;
    }
    return base;
}
```

Finally, when we have a `while` loop or a recursion, it is always good to know the worst case of how many iterations the program may need to perform.

In this case the question is: starting from an odd number `n`, what is the maximal value of the next prime, i.e. the smallest prime, `p`, such that p >= n?

To the help comes [Bertrand's Postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) (which despite the name is actually a theorem) saying that p<2*n. Thus for a given starting value of `base`, `primeFinder()` will run at most about `base/2` iterations (since we increment the guess by 2 for each iteration).

Thus, the worst case complexity of `primeFinder()` is O(n^(3/2)).